# Java 8 Filtering a list within a list

Tags: java, lambda

I have a list of objects which contain a list of objects and I want to get one of the items within the container.  Is this possible to do with a lambda or just need to nest for loops?

Here's the current method I use for finding an item:

```
for (Container c : containers) {
    for (Item i : c.getItems() {
        if (i.getKey().equals(key)) return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like `containers.stream().flatMap(c -> c.getItems().stream()).filter(i -> i.getKey().equals(key)).findFirst().orElse(null);`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard I did not see your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nested for-loops works well. If you want to do it using streams, you can do this:

```
containers.stream()
          .flatMap(c -> c.getItems().stream())
          .filter(i -> i.getKey().equals(key))
          .findFirst();
```

This returns an `Optional` that contains the `Item` if it was found, or an empty `Optional` otherwise.